# Плагины для Sublime PHP

Tags: sublime-text

Есть ли плагин,который позволяет при наведении на функцию просматривать какие параметры ей передавать? И если есть еще какие то удобные плагины для удобства при работе с PHP,прошу поделиться а

Comment: Тут много хороших плагинов перечисленно, как их учтанавливать и некоторые настройки для них (на английском): https://mattstauffer.com/blog/sublime-text-3-for-php-developers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из наиболее полезных, я бы отметил:

1. [SublimeCodeIntel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) для автокомплита и прочих плюшек, облегчающих набор кода.
2. [SublimeLinter-php](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-php) для проверки кода на корректность синтаксиса и соответствие стандартам оформления. Это, кстати говоря, модуль для [SublimeLinter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter), так что надо будет установить для начала и его.
3. [PhpDoc](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PhpDoc) как ни странно добавит поддержку PhpDoc. Вероятно, Вы найдёте его полезным.

Как Вы наверняка заметили, для управления плагинами рекомендую пользоваться удобнейшим [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation). Да, упомянуто не так много плагинов, но и SublimeText всё же редактор (хоть и очень умный), а не IDE. Для дальнейших поисков тех плагинов, которые необходимы именно в Вашем случае (xdebug, phpunit, git?), советую воспользоваться вышеупомянутым Package Control -- он замечательно ищет по ключевым словам.